# Crystal repo download - ExportToHttpResponse is downloading file without extension

Tags: asp.net, pdf, crystal-reports, report, file-extension

```
 rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Rpt/CallPendingReport.rpt"));
                rptDoc.SetDataSource(dtData);
                Session["ReportDataSet"] = rptDoc;
                crvCallPendingReport.ReportSource = rptDoc;
                crvCallPendingReport.DataBind();
                // crvMasterCallReport.RefreshReport();
                rptDoc.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "CallPendingReport" + DateTime.Now + ".pdf");
```

Problem in cry repo download - ExportToHttpResponse is downloading file without extension ,
i am trying to download report pdf file with file name as per code, but it is downloading the file with out extension.
any body knowing the solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Rpt/CallPendingReport.rpt"));
                rptDoc.SetDataSource(dtData);
                Session["ReportDataSet"] = rptDoc;
                crvCallPendingReport.ReportSource = rptDoc;
                crvCallPendingReport.DataBind();
                // crvMasterCallReport.RefreshReport();
                rptDoc.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "CallPendingReport"+ DateTime.Now + ".pdf");
```

Comment: Check the file name, it contains the space, so the Problem occures.